# node-Inspector with selenium webdriver not working

Tags: node.js, selenium, node-inspector

I am trying to write automated tests using node.js, mocha.js and selenium web-driver. I have installed node-inspector. For now I am just trying to get node.js, Selenium and node-inspector to work together. Once I accomplish this I will use mocha. If I run the node file with selenium I see my code being executed on the browser. However when I run the command `node-debug first_test.js` into the command line. I get this error:

```
Node Inspector is now available from http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
Debugging `first_test.js`

debugger listening on port 5858
`parseFile()` is deprecated. Use `parseString()` instead.
`parseString()` is deprecated. It's not actually async. Use `parse()` instead.
```

My node.js (first_test.js) is below:

```
 var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

 var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
 withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
 build();

 driver.get('http://www.google.com');
 driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
 debugger;
 driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
 //driver.quit();
```